# How to put nested fields_for code directly in parent _form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

How can I rewrite the code in **`duels/_form`** so I can put the code from **`dueler_fields`** directly in there?

**`duels/_form`**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :consequence %>
  <%= f.text_field :reward %>
  <%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %>
    <%= render 'dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association f, :duelers do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Dueler
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**`_dueler_fields`**

```
# I want to place these two lines of code in the _form
<%= f.number_field :user_id, placeholder: "Enter User ID" %>
<%= f.number_field :challenge_id, placeholder: "Enter Challenge ID" %>
```

**`duels_controller`**

```
def new
  @duel = Duel.new
  respond_with(@duel)
end
```

`duels` `has_many` `duelers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `f` to `dueler` and you should be good to go. or:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :consequence %>
  <%= f.text_field :reward %>
  <%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler_form| %>
    <%= dueler_form.number_field :user_id, placeholder: "Enter User ID" %>
    <%= dueler_form.number_field :challenge_id, placeholder: "Enter Challenge ID" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey sorry. It didn't work. Maybe I didn't explain enough. I updated code. I want to leave `<%= render 'dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>`, but I also want to put directly in the _form `<%= f.number_field :user_id, placeholder: "Enter User ID" %>`
`<%= f.number_field :challenge_id, placeholder: "Enter Challenge ID" %>` so I can equal the ones directly in the form to the `current_user`

Comment: hm, maybe in your controller prefill a "dueler"? `@duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user: current_user)`?

Comment: Oh perfect! That's what I was trying to get at. Thank you!